# What box extender to use for dryer outlet?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, wainscoting

I am planning on putting beadboard wainscoting on a laundry room wall. I will need to add an extender to the dryer's 240v outlet to keep it to electrical code and have the outlet sit flush up against the extender. The beadboard will add 3/16" thickness to the wall.

I can't find a suitable product to use. I've used [these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Steel-City-1-Gang-Metal-Electrical-Switch-Box-Extension-SBEX-25R/202591768) in the past for 1-gang outlets, but there doesn't seem to be one for the bigger box. Which product should I use?

Here's a picture of the box, it is plastic and W: 3.75" H: 3.5":

[image]

Comment: Do you have a picture of the box in question?  There are a few different boxes it could be.

Comment: Yes, can you post a photo of the box in question please?

Comment: I've added a picture of the box now. It is plastic measuring around 3.75" wide and 3.5" tall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use an Arlington BE2

What you have appears to be a two gang plastic box, so you'll need a two gang plastic box extender such as the Arlington BE2 or equivalent (picture below is of a BE2, but for illustration only.  These should be available at any supply house worth its chops, and can even be ordered from the orange borg if you can't get it any other way.

[image: Arlington BE2]